# Part of my CSS file doesn't render on my ejs file

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

Somehow only part of my CSS renders on my ejs file (eg: `<footer>` tags) and the rest of my CSS doesn't render at all.
I tried to define the path of my static files to my views directory by the path method: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` and I linked my **main.css** file to my **header.ejs** file: `<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`, but it still renders only the footer's CSS style and not the rest.

CODES:

**index.js:**

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import axios from "axios";
//import favicon from "serve-favicon";
import * as path from 'path';
import * as url from 'url';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const API_URL = "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php";
const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

//app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public','images','cup-straw.svg'))); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { 'extensions': ['html', 'htm'], 'index': false, 'maxAge': '1d', 'setHeaders': (res, path, stat) => { res.set('Content-Type', 'text/css'); } }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.ejs")
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(API_URL);
        const result = response.data;
        console.log(result, "Drink has been submitted.");
        res.render("index.ejs", {drink: result});
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.result, "Error in the server has occurred!");
        res.status(500);
     } 
});



app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

**main.css:**

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}

footer {
    color: green;
}
```

**header.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" href="/Backend/Capstone Project - Public API/public/images/cup-straw.svg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>The Cocktails Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
```

**index.ejs:**

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>

    <h1>Cocktails</h1>
    <br />

<main>


<h2>Your drink:</h2>
<% if (locals.drink) { %>
  <div class="cocktail-box"></div>
  <% drink.drinks.forEach(drinkDetail => { %>
   <li><%= drinkDetail.strDrink %></li>
   <div class="ingr">
   <h3>Ingredients</h3>
   <% for( let i = 1; i < 16; i++ ) { %>
    <% if (drinkDetail['strIngredient' + i] != null) { %>
      <li><%= drinkDetail['strMeasure' + i] %> of <%= drinkDetail['strIngredient' + i] %></li>
    <% } %>
   <% } %>
   </div>
   <div class="ins">
   <h3>Instructions</h3>
   <li><%= drinkDetail.strInstructions %></li>  
   </div>
   <div>
    <img src="<%= drinkDetail.strDrinkThumb %>" alt="cocktail"/>
   </div>
  <% }) %>
  </div>
<% } %>
 
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" name="buttonDrink" id="buttonClick">GET A DRINK</button>
  </form>


</main>

<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

**footer.ejs:**

```
<footer>
    Footer
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Furthermore, the Network tab shows that the **main.css** file works perfectly fine, but the stylesheet keeps on cancelling my background color for my `body` element. See the screenshots: [image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me, I've been struggling with this issue for a long time and I really don't know what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `bootstrap@5.3.2` which is a CSS and JS Component library. Your `background-color` is being being overwritten by a Bootstrap CSS selector which has more specificity or is loaded after your own `main.css` file.

You can either link your `main.css` after the Bootstrap one or just make your CSS selector more specific:

```css
#body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
```

Comment: Yes you're right! I removed the bootstrap and it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: @YuvalYanay you're welcome. If you found the answer useful please consider [marking as accpted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)